# How do I find the top left of my SVG with d3?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

Given an SVG created with d3, for example using

```
svg = d3.select("#someElement").append("svg")...
```

how do I find the top and left of the SVG in the absolute coordinates of the `body`, so that I can, for example, absolutely position a tooltip or other element relative to the top -left of the SVG with something like

```
tooltip.style("left", leftInBody + 72 + "px").style("top", topInBody + 20 + "px");
```

Comment: the top left of your svg, unless scales set it otherwise, is simply 0,0

Comment: @tomtomtom: In the `body`?

Comment: no, the coordinates in the svg area start from 0,0 in the top-left corner. otherwise you can use the methods posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (with jQuery):

```
var offset = $('#someElement svg').offset(),
    left = offset.left, top = offset.top;
```

also assuming that you're tooltip is a `div` outside of the root svg element.

If the tooltip is an svg element inside the root svg element, then you don't need to do this. The position you give it will automatically be relative to the root svg element.

Comment: Is there no d3 idiom for the position of the top or left of a given SVG within the `body`?

Comment: Surprisingly, this looks like the way to go: jQuery is the answer.

Comment: Hi @orome check the other answer

Comment: @PeterKrauss Great to see that d3 no supports this. Tone that answer down a bit at it will get some votes.

Answer (score 0):

@victormejia answer  **is WRONG** because is so old... We are in 2019 and D3 is so good!

Use `d3.select(myElement).style('top')`, `d3.select(myElement).style('left')`.

Use `parseInt()` to clean the "px" string... 
PS: to set a value, concatenate "px", `d3.select(myElement).style('left',x+'px')`.